# Cómo usar jQuery Ajax POST con Google Apps Script para mostrar una página de agradecimiento personalizada

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-apps-script

Quiero enviar los datos del formulario a una hoja de Google, a través de un script, la cual me redirige a un json en el que indica que se ha realizado correctamente y me indica en que fila se ha guardado. Lo que yo quiero es que no vaya a esa página si no que vaya a una página de agradecimiento.

**Edit**: El error está en que no redirige a la página que quiero, sigue redirigiéndome a la página del script de google, como si ignorase el script.

**Edit 2:** El script de google es la siguiente aplicación web. [Web App](https://gist.github.com/matthaliski/4253339)

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="formID" action="gscript">
...
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
   $(document).on('submit', '.formID', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) {
        alert('ok');
        window.location("pagina de agradecimiento");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

Comment: te muestra el 'ok' del alert?

Comment: No @JoséMiguelSepulveda

Comment: @David: La pregunta está incompleta porque no has indicado cómo estás enviando los datos  a la hoja de Google ¿estás usando un web app, la execution api u otra cosa? Por otro lado para simplificar la pregunta podrías intentar primero hacer lo mismo sin usar Google Apps Script, por ejemplo, pasando los datos del formulario a la consola.

Comment: Ahora lo edito, de todas formas, los datos los pasa correctamente.

Comment: Las preguntas sobre código que no funciona, deben incluir un [mcve].

Comment: Tal vez fuera de tema, pero el código de la web app incluye UiApp, el cual está "descontinuado" (deprecated). Referencia https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app. Mejor prueba con este otro https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293

Comment: Pensandolo bien, no está fuera de tema. El problema real es que la aplicación web no devuelve un mensaje de éxito/fracaso. Sugiero replantear el título a algo como "Cómo usar jQuery Ajax POST con Google Apps Script para mostrar una página de agradecimiento personalizada"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recién se agregó el enlace al [código usado](https://gist.github.com/matthaliski/4253339) para la aplicación web creada usando Google Apps Script. Ese código tiene varios problemas

1. Usa un método deprecado (obsoleto), específicamente [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app).
2. No incluye devolver una respuesta ni en caso de éxito (success) ni en caso de falla (failure).

En lugar de ese ejemplo, mejor usar este otro https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293. Nótese que este incluye el uso de [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) para crear las respuestas tanto para el caso de éxito como de falla.

```
  try{
    // ...

    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
```

A continuación un ejemplo

```js
$( "#formulario" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzhZaMeboekcH7VxNBh2lS-wYyKb07je2hqsKIl_HKFTiASNJUb/exec",
    data: '',
    success: function(){
      alert( "Gracias" );
      $(document.body).html("Se dieron las gracias");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Código de la aplicación web llamada por el código previo

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    // Hacer algo
    var nextRow = 1;
    // devolver JSON éxito (success)
    return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // en caso de error devolver esto
    return ContentService
     .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
     .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally {
    // En cualquier caso, terminar realizando lo siguiente
  }
}
```

---

La pregunta se puede simplificar a

> ¿Cómo hacer que el formulario de la respuesta que yo quiero al usuario?

Para fines de simplicidad, digamos que "lo que yo quiero" es mostrar una alerta y escribir un mensaje en la página.

La forma básica de especificar lo que se debe hacer al enviar un formulario, es a través del atributo `onsubmit`. En este puedes colocar el código JavaScript

```html
<form id="formulario" onsubmit="window.alert('Gracias'); document.write('Se dieron las gracias')">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Si decides que todo se controle a través de un script, entonces pon `onsubmit="miScript"`

```js
function miScript() {
  window.alert('Gracias'); document.write('Se dieron las gracias');
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" action="" onsubmit="miScript()" >
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

A continuación lo mismo, pero usando jQuery, en el cual se debe incluir `preventDefault` para lograr lo que se está buscando.

```js
$( "#formulario" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert( "Gracias" );
  $(document.body).html("Se dieron las gracias");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formulario">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Me funciona bien ya, pero dónde debo colocar el script de google para que este funcione? Probé en el `action` del formulario pero no hace nada.

Comment: Acabo de añadir un link a la web app que uso

Comment: Ok, he cambiado el código de la aplicación web, pero sigue igual

Comment: Ya funciona, gracias por todo.https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/65/rub%c3%a9n

Answer (score 3):

Veo un error en el selector del formulario: debería ser '#formID' en lugar de '.formID'.

Prueba utilizando la sintaxis de promesas y mandando la información completa del posible error a la consola:

```js
   $(document).on('submit', '#formID', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize()
     }).done(function (html) {
         alert('ok');
         window.location.href = 'http://www.milejemplos.com/frases/frases-de-agradecimiento';
     }).fail(function(jqXhr, msg) {
          var responseText = jqXhr.responseText || '';
          console.log(msg + ':\n' + responseText);
     });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="formID" action="">
 <input type="text" name="campo" />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Acabo de añadir algo más, no sé como explicarlo mejor.

Comment: En realidad sí te va a ignorar el script por el error en el selector que te comento.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva tiene razon. No te tomará la función por que estara buscando una clase y no un `id`

Comment: Incluso con ese cambio sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo en el que debería mandar la información del error a la consola para ver qué es lo que está fallando.

Comment: No envía ningún error, no me sale nada en la consola.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cosas que ver, el `window.location`, es con `window.location.href` y no es un método, es una propiedad, y aparte cuando el selector es para un ID se utiliza `#` y no `.` Saludos.

```js
   $(function(){
      $('#formID').submit(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
              url: $('#formID').attr('action'),
              type: $('#formID').attr('method'),
              data: $('#formID').serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                alert('ok');
                window.location.href = 'pagina de agradecimiento';
              },
              error: function(ort, rt, qrt){
                console.log('hay un error');
                console.log(ort);
              }
          });
      });
   });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="formID" action="gscript">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Sigue igual, lo único que ahora abre la respuesta del gscript en una ventana nueva

Comment: ¿Que error te bota, o no te sale nada?

Comment: No me sale nada. Estoy mirando en la consola de google chrome, no estoy muy familiarizado con la programación web y no sé si se mira en otro lado.

Comment: ¿Y no te aparece ningún error? Mira también en la pestaña "Network", aunque si hay algún error ahí también debería aparecer en la consola.

Comment: No, tampoco, es como si fuese directo al action con el script y no pasase por el script, es la sensación que me da a mi.

Comment: y bueno, cual debería ser la secuencia correcta. ejemplo como normalmente se ejecutaba el proceso, sin tu código adherido como hacia antes el procedimiento.

Comment: No entiendo lo que me quieres preguntar. Pero, yo he creado un formulario con datos básicos (nombre, apellido, edad...) y para enviarlos a una hoja de google los envío a través del script que se colca en el action del form, al darle al botón de submit este envía los datos pero además redirige al usuario a una página con un informe de que los datos han llegado. Lo que intento añadir con el script es que en lugar de redirigir a esa página lo haga a una nueva

Comment: @David y ejecuta ese procedimiento, osea ingresa los datos a la hoja de google pero no muestra el mensaje?

Comment: Exacto @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver